# truncating a Utf8 column of a polars LazyFrame to a certain number of characters

Tags: python-polars

I'm preparing some files for upload to a database using `polars`'s `scan_csv`.

Some of the columns contain very long text which needs to be truncated to a given number of characters, otherwise the upload will fail.

What is the best way to modify a `LazyFrame` object produced by `scan_csv` such that all `pl.Utf8` columns have at most some specified number of characters?

I know the columns to be modified can be identified by inspecting the `schema` attribute.

### Example Data:

Given some mock data:

```py
# pretend this comes from scan_csv()
example = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "big_column": ["a" * 1000],
        "another_big_column": ["b" * 1000],
        "small_column": ["c"],
        "integer_column": [1]
    },
    schema = {
        "big_column": pl.Utf8,
        "another_big_column": pl.Utf8,
        "small_column": pl.Utf8,
        "integer_column": pl.Int8
    }
).lazy()
```

I'm imagining we can do something like:

```py
for col, dtype in example.schema.items():
    if dtype is pl.Utf8:
        # do something with col
```

### Questions:

What should the `# do something with col` part of the above be to achieve what I want **without** loading the entire `LazyFrame` into memory?

Is it even possible to perform such a modification in-place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a datatype to [`pl.col`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.col.html) to select all columns of that type.

```
df.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Utf8).str.slice(0, 10)).collect()
```

```
shape: (1, 4)
┌────────────┬────────────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────┐
│ big_column ┆ another_big_column ┆ small_column ┆ integer_column │
│ ---        ┆ ---                ┆ ---          ┆ ---            │
│ str        ┆ str                ┆ str          ┆ i8             │
╞════════════╪════════════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════╡
│ aaaaaaaaaa ┆ bbbbbbbbbb         ┆ c            ┆ 1              │
└────────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────┘
```